# SwiftUI Map not updating after center changes

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, refresh

I'm unsure why my SwiftUI map is updating when I update mapRegion.center with a new coordinate from spot.coordinate, but not when I update it with my locationManager value. If I run the code below, first when a spot.coordinate is used, the map shifts without a problem & I see the map change. If I run it when there is no spot & pass in a location, though, I don't move from the map's 0, 0 coordinates.

```
.onAppear {
    print("mapRegion.center BEFORE = \(mapRegion.center)")
    annotations = [Annotation(name: spot.name, address: spot.address, coordinate: spot.coordinate)]
    if spot.id != nil { // If we have a spot, make that the center, otherwise continue to use user location
        mapRegion.center = spot.coordinate
    } else {
        guard let newCenter = locationManager.location?.coordinate else {
            print("*** Couldn't get proper newCenter")
            return
        }
        mapRegion.center = newCenter
    }
    print("mapRegion.center AFTER = \(mapRegion.center)")
}
```

Output from the 1st and 2nd case shows the update:

```
mapRegion.center BEFORE = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
mapRegion.center AFTER = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.66078178848971, longitude: -70.61446845531464)
mapRegion.center BEFORE = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
mapRegion.center AFTER = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.335795, longitude: -71.17047933673686)
```

Any thoughts on mapRegion is bound to the map as the coordinate region.

Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 1):

Unsure why, but if I put the code updating the mapRegion.center from the locationManager inside a Task {} block, it now works. Surprising since print statements showed the update. It's also noted that if I wrap everything in the Task block, I get the "purple warnings" about "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior."

```
.onAppear {
    annotations = [Annotation(name: spot.name, address: spot.address, coordinate: spot.coordinate)]
    if spot.id != nil { // If we have a spot, make that the center, otherwise continue to use user location
        mapRegion.center = spot.coordinate
    } else {
        Task {
            mapRegion.center = locationManager.location?.coordinate ?? CLLocationCoordinate2D()
        }
    }
}
```